# Destructuring array parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I'm learning about destructuring and had a quick query on how to refer to the elements of an array.

I'm destructuring a nested array within an object in a function's parameter using:

```
function ajaxOptions({
    url,
    headers: [ 
        header0 ="Content-Type: text/plain",
        ...otherHeaders
    ] = [],
    data
} = {}) { 
    //... function body
}
```

which is giving a default value to the first element, `header0` and spreading the other array elements.

But if I had a settings object:

```
var settings = {
    url: 'http://someothersite.com', 
    data: 50, 
    callback: sayHello, 
    headers: [,  'Header2', 'Header3'] 
}
```

and passed it to `ajaxOptions(settings)` I can't use `header0` in the settings object to refer to the array element that's destructured in ajaxOptions can I? In other words I can't use it as a named argument like 'url', 'data' and 'callback' kind of are?

Hope that makes sense. Here's the complete code if it helps:

```
function ajaxOptions({
    url: url = "http://www.example.com",
    method: method = "post",
    headers: [ 
        header0 ="Content-Type: text/plain",
        ...otherHeaders
    ] = [],
    data: data,
    callback: callback 

} = {}) {
    return { url, method, headers: [header0, ...otherHeaders], data, callback};
}

function sayHello(){
    console.log('hello');
}


var defaults = ajaxOptions();

var settings = {
    url: 'http://someothersite.com', 
    data: 50, 
    callback: sayHello, 
    headers: [, header0 = 'New Header', 'Header2', 'Header3'] 
}

console.log(ajaxOptions(settings));
```

Thanks

Comment: I am rereading... but I don't understand what you are asking. The code that follows "So", is that parameter code, or calling code? It would be good if you would include full code of something that does not do what you wanted it to do. So we can reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's not entirely straight in my head so is difficult to explain. I've reworded the example, and the final code block produces an object that has an array with the 'Content-Type', 'New Header', 'Header2' and 'Header3' values. Bascially I can't change that element by name

I guess what I'm saying is - in the destructured object parameter, what does the `header0` name actually do?

Comment: What you mean by "*I couldn't use the name header0 to effect the value in the array*"? What is the problem with the code you have, doesn't it work? If no, what's the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header0` in your parameter list is a parameter, a local variable, just like `a` is a parameter in:

```
function test(a) { }
```

And just like you cannot reference `a` by name outside of that `test` function, neither can you do that with your code and `header0`. So if you call your function with  `header0 =`, you are actually defining a global variable `header0` and assigning it a value on the spot. It would produce an error in strict mode. It has nothing to do with the parameter `header0`.

The parameter `header0` will get its value from the first element of the array you pass as `headers` property value. If the object you pass as argument does not have the `headers` property, or that property does not define a first array element that is different from `undefined`, then the local `headers0` variable will get the default value.

This variable is not to be confused with the property name followed by a colon, that also appears in your parameter section: `headers:`. This is not a variable, but is merely defining the spot from where variables `headers0` and `otherHeaders` should get their values when the function is called. But `headers` itself is not a variable.

`url` on the other hand *is* a variable. It takes its value from the property with the same name. Notice the lack of the colon. That makes it a variable (parameter).

The syntax used in destructuring can be quite confusing. For instance, if instead of `url,` you would have `url: url2`, then instead of defining variable `url`, you define variable `url2` -- still being the value that the `url` property has in the object that you pass to the function.

Comment: You can name a fixed number of them, for instance when in the parameter definition you put `headers: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...others]`, you will have variable names (inside the function only) for the first few elements of the array. But outside of the function these names do not exist.

Comment: ah so it's because with url, for example, I'm destructuring it to a variable with the same name, url. But that isn't happening for the array. ok, think i've got it. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to solve your problem with objects to reference the array index. But if all you really want is to have an array that returns the first values within a function you could try to arrange the arrays as follows.

```
const defaulHeader = ["Content-Type: text/plain"]
const otherHeaders = ["Some-type: application/json"]

 const headers = [ 
        ...defaulHeader,
        ...otherHeaders
    ]

console.log(headers)
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, but I'm more referring to the use of `header0`. So for example `url` can be used in the settings object to change the url value in the destructured parameter. But I don't think `header0` can be used in that way

Comment: so in the settings object having `headers: [header0 = 'newHeader',  'Header2', 'Header3']`, only works because it's in position 0, not because it's called `header0`